# Call function in app.component from page.ts [IONIC4]

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

If I have a function in:

results.ts

```
export class ResultsPage implements OnInit {

    myFunc() {
       alert('my function works!');
    }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="myFunc()">CALL</button>
```

can I call this function in my app.component.html?

Answer (score 1):

You should use angular providers and services

run `ionic g service SomeProvider`

inside SomeProvider create your function

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SomeProvider {

    constructor() {

    }

    someFunction(){
        console.log("I do something useful!");
    }

}
```

set up as a **provider** in the **app.module.ts** file:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    SomeProvider // <-- List providers here
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

inject into classes that want to use them:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SomeProvider } from '../../providers/some-provider/some-provider';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-something',
  templateUrl: 'something.html',
})
export class SomePage {
    constructor(public myService: SomeService) {

    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.myService.someFunction(); // This will log "I do something useful!"
    }

}
```

Here you can find complete guide: https://www.joshmorony.com/when-to-use-providersservicesinjectables-in-ionic/

Comment: works fine with simple function, but I have a problem with json rendering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549888/get-json-api-from-servcice-ionic-4