# Render JSON in html from Service [Ionic 4]

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Thanks to parrycima, I created my first service.

results.service.ts

```
  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {

  }

  async checkFunc() {

    this.apiurl = 'https://my.apiurl.com/';

    this.httpService.get(this.apiurl).subscribe(res => {

         if (res) {
          this.items = Object.keys(res).map(function(key) {
           return res[key];
          });
         }

        }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         console.log (err.message);
        }
      );

  }
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(
        public myService: ResultsService,
        private httpService: HttpClient
      ) {

       this.myService.checkFunc();

    }
```

app.component.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-item>{{item.operator}} 
      <div class="icon-status" slot="end">
        <ion-icon name="{{item.status}}"></ion-icon>
      </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I can get object only in console mode, but not in HTML rendered.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD3mA.jpg

With the same function I can rendering HTML fine in result.page.ts.

Answer (score 1):

From your service return this.items

```
async checkFunc() {

this.apiurl = 'https://my.apiurl.com/';

await this.httpService.get(this.apiurl).subscribe(res => {

     if (res) {
      this.items = Object.keys(res).map(function(key) {
       return res[key];
      });
      return this.items
     }

    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
     console.log (err.message);
    }
  );

}


export class AppComponent {
   items;
    constructor(
      public myService: ResultsService,
      private httpService: HttpClient
     ) {

   this.items = this.myService.checkFunc();

 }
```

Comment: thank you for help. Get this error: AppComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Promise]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.